# Android OpenGl ES Triangle Fan

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I'm trying to use OpenGL in my app, and have therefore copy pasted [this](http://androidblog.reindustries.com/a-real-open-gl-es-2-0-2d-tutorial-part-1/) code into my project. It works perfectly, but I want to draw triangle fans instead of just drawing that triangle. How do i change the code so that I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no magic about using triangle fans. You simply change the primitive type that gets passed as the first argument to the draw calls to `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN`. For example, where your tutorial code currently has this call:

```
GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, indices.length,
        GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, drawListBuffer);
```

You change it to this instead:

```
GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, indices.length,
        GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, drawListBuffer);
```

Now you simply add more vertices and indices, and you're ready to go to town.

The way OpenGL defines triangle fans, the first point is shared by all triangles. If you specify vertices:

```
v0 v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6 ...
```

the generated triangles are:

```
v0 v1 v2
v0 v2 v3
v0 v3 v4
v0 v4 v5
v0 v5 v6
...
```

A related primitive type are triangle strips (`GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP`), which are more commonly used than triangle fans.

Answer (score -1):

Triangle fan doesn't exist in opengl es directly. If you want to create triangle fans you'll need to draw using triangles and indicies. Here's a pretty good tutorial on how to make that work. http://www.learnopengles.com/tag/triangle-strips/

Comment: ok, thanks. Thought I still don't know how to implement this into my code.

Comment: In the case of the tutorial you posted it's pretty straightforward. Just updated the setupTriangle method to add the extra triangle vertices you want in your fan and then add the indicies as shown in the example I posted. The drawing code should all remain the same.

Comment: This is totally wrong. Triangle fans are supported in all versions of OpenGL ES.